# Entity Framework apply filter to parent and child object

Tags: linq-to-entities

Trying to keep my description simple, let's assume I have an `Order` object which contains a list of `LineItem` objects.

I need to apply a filter that can be quite complex to find certain `Orders` based on a `LineItem` criteria. Simplified example:

```
var orders = db.Order.Where(o => o.LineItems.Any(li => li.Price == 1.00));
```

This will give me the correct `Orders`, but when I expand `Order.LineItems`, I get all the `LineItems`, not just the ones that were filtered.

It seems that I need to apply the filter again to `Order.LineItems` for each `Order` I process? As I said earlier, the selection criteria could be quite complex with 30 or more where clauses.

Is there a simpler way to write the query?

Comment: You don't need to perform another query. Your first query will return all orders with at-least one line item such that it has Price of 1.00. So when you are accessing line items of an order later check if its has Price equal to 1.00 or not.

Comment: @ShoaibShakeel As I stated, the query could be quite complex so looping through all the line items and applying the filter one at a time isn't really a solution. Need the filter to happen on the sql server and only bring down that information. The "order" and "line item" was just a way to simplify the question. There are hundreds of thousands of "orders" with millions of "line items".

Comment: Why not `var liGroups = db.LineItems.Where(li => li.Price == 1.00).GroupBy(li => li.Order);` ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim I think you've got me going in the right direction. If you'll post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return `LineItems` grouped by `Order`

```
var liGroups = db.LineItems.Where(li => li.Price == 1.00).GroupBy(li => li.Order);
```